# Passing JSON to Controller MVC3 C# .NET

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I´m trying to pass my data(json) from view through ajax to my controller but this arrive null. Thanks in advance fro any help or suggestion.

This is my model.

```
public class TipificacionModel
{
    public int Existente { get; set; }
    public string Campo { get; set; }
    public int Regla { get; set; }

}

public class ListasSeleccionModel{
    public List<string> DatosSeleccion { get; set; }
}

public class ListaTipificaciones
{
    public string NombreCampaña { get; set; }
    public List<TipificacionModel> Tipificacion { get; set; }
}

public class DatosSeleccionMultiple
{
    public List<String> Columnas { get; set; }
    public List<ListasSeleccionModel> ListasSeleccion { get; set; }
}

public class TipificacionGeneralCampaña
{
    public ListaTipificaciones CamposCreados { get; set; }
    public List<DatosSeleccionMultiple> ListasDeSeleccion { get; set; }

}
```

This is my ajax function.

```
        jsonListaGeneral = [];

        jsonListaGeneral.push(jsonTipificacion);
        jsonListaGeneral.push(jsonListasSeleccion);

        console.log(jsonListaGeneral);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("crearCampManual", "DPS")',
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonListaGeneral),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response)
                return;
            },
            error: function (x) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });
```

This is my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult crearCampManual(TipificacionGeneralCampaña model)
    { //Here the model value is null, why?}
```

When i print the json in my browser console everything is good. But something bad happends, im making something wrong.

[Console Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA5JF.png)

[Break Point Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU5nJ.png)

Comment: JSON.stringify turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string....so you are just sending an string into you controller method...try removing the `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Can you add the structure of the data you are passing through your ajax call? I often run into this problem when the property names on my JSON object don't match the property names on my C# model.

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks for your answer, removing stringify Ajax dont found my controller. Error 500 in my browser console.

Comment: @LukeTBrooks, Thanks for your soon answer, please checj the Console Browser image, there is the structure of the data that im trying to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that the data you are sending through your AJAX call appears to be an Array:

```
jsonListaGeneral = [];
```

But your C# model isn't an array or collection:

```
public ActionResult crearCampManual(TipificacionGeneralCampaña model)
```

If you are sending an array of TipificacionGeneralCampaña objects from your AJAX to your C# Controller, then you would want your Controller definition to look like this:

```
public ActionResult crearCampManual(List<TipificacionGeneralCampaña> model)
```

And also to reiterate what @Hackereman stated in his comment, you do not need to use the JSON.Stringify function on your data before you pass it to your Controller:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("crearCampManual", "DPS")',
        type: 'post',
        data: jsonListaGeneral,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response)
            return;
        },
        error: function (x) {
            alert(x.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Another issue that I noticed from your Console Browser screenshot: you seem to be adding two different objects to the same JSON array before sending to your controller:

```
    jsonListaGeneral.push(jsonTipificacion);
    jsonListaGeneral.push(jsonListasSeleccion);
```

When creating a collection in C#, all objects in the collect need to be of the same type, meaning that they have the same Property Names and Property Types.

With how your C# Controller is currently setup, it will accept a JSON object that is structured like this:

```
{
    CamposCreados : {
        NombreCampaña : "",
        Tipificacion : [
            {
                Existente  : 0,
                Campo : "",
                Regla : 0
            },
            {
                Existente  : 1,
                Campo : "",
                Regla : 1
            }
        ]
    }
    ListasDeSeleccion : [
        {
            Columnas : "",
            ListasSeleccion : [
                {
                    DatosSeleccion : [
                        {
                            "",
                            "",
                            ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    DatosSeleccion : [
                        {
                            "",
                            "",
                            ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help my friends, @Luke T Brooks  give me the key of the issue. I was sending an array an the controller was expected for an object.  The solution was change the declaration of `var jsonListaGeneral = {
                "CamposCreados": jsonTipificacion,
                "ListasDeSeleccion": jsonListasSeleccion
            }`. About the JSON.stringify is necesary for receive the data in other case this show error 500. Now works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is change the declaration of the Json Object.

```
var jsonListaGeneral = {
    "CamposCreados": jsonTipificacion,
    "ListasDeSeleccion": jsonListasSeleccion
}
```